# Lipschitz and derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

> Show that if $f$ is bounded function on $E$ that belongs to $L^p_1(E)$, then it belongs to $L^p_2(E)$ for any $P_2 > P_1$.

I am totally clueless on how to start. Is $f$ an element in a normed linear space? If so do I have liberty in defining the norm?

Comment: The spaces $L^p $ come with the standard norm $||f||_p:=(\int_E f^p)^{1/p}$. Seems reasonable to assume this is the one being used unless otherwise-stated . Also: do you have $m(E) < \infty$ ?

Comment: @jcir  Yes this is a function on a normed space and  user99680 has stated the norm, which is standard.  He is also getting at something very important -- f belonging to a space with lower p implies belonging to a space with higher p depends on the whether the measure of E is finite.

Comment: @JCIR: think of doing a trick using Holder's ineq. You don't have necessarily that $1/p+1/q=1$ , but you can find a trick around it.

Answer (score 0):

If $|f|\le M$, then $|f|^{p_2}\le M^{p_2-p_1}|f|^{p_1}$. The right hand side is integrable.